# (jQuery Highchart) Is there any way to put extra custom data inside Tooltip Box?

Tags: jquery, tooltip, highcharts

I want to add extra **custom** statistic data lines inside Tooltip Box, which appears over mouse hover. As far as i've learned, it shows only the data inside the object arrays called `series:` and `tooltip:`.

I just wanna put more custom data (into Tooltip Box) **with seperated values for each of Tooltip** (NOT COMMON ONE).

For example:
Bar 1 =========================== 41% `Tooltip: Water: 7.86%`
Bar 2 ================= 33% `Tooltip: Salt: 5.2%, Water: 80%`
Bar 3 ====================== 35% `Tooltip: Caffeine: 51%, Alcohol: 31%, Water: 4%`

**Tooltip items & values for each bar are different**. How can i?

Answer (score 9):

You can store this information with the `series`, like the following.

```
{
    type: 'bar',
    name: 'Bar3',
    composition: {
        'Caffeine': '51%',
        'Alcohol': '31%',
        'Water': '4%'
    },
    data: [35]
}
```

Then you can get it through the tooltip formatter. Use `this` to reference the series.

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        console.log(this.series.options.composition);
    }
}
```

Then you only have to format the text according to what you want.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YXetx/)

Reference:

- [Tooltip formatter](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#tooltip--formatter)

Comment: @4lvin Updated with an example.

Comment: Ah but it is now showing separated labels beside. I mean, it is showing only one label "00:00:00.000" for all bars. I just need labels for each bars. Can it possible pls?

Comment: Actually, it is EXACTLY likely with: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked
But unfortunately it is vertical. What i need is horizontal one.

Comment: @4lvin You have to set your serie type to bar.

Comment: Or use inverted with true value. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.inverted

Comment: Is this only for Highstocks?  this.series is undefined for me in Highcharts...type = column.

Comment: @Terry Try to set `tooltip.shared` as `false`.

Comment: I think the problem was that I had multiple series in my chart.  So I had to work with the .points property to retrieve the .series object.