# How to add third set of data for use in Highcharts tooltip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, tooltip

I have a chart which shows points, when I hover over these points the co-ordinates of the point is shown. [image]

I want to add a third line to this tooltip showing the date associated with the point. I have added this date to the raw data fed to the graph but I'm not sure how to make it show in this box? Basically I want to add a different value into MY DATE VALUE below for every point. How can this be done?

```
  tooltip: {
       borderRadius: 10,
       formatter: function () {
            return 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
                '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>' + MY DATE VALUE;
        }
    },
```

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17175632/highcharts-passing-additional-information-to-a-tooltip and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594031/jquery-highchart-is-there-any-way-to-put-extra-custom-data-inside-tooltip-box and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294326/highcharts-pass-multiple-values-to-tooltip ....

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514457/set-additional-data-to-highcharts-series